How to Install Xapian in PHP 7.0
We were using PHP 5.6 and installed Xapian 1.2.24. It was working fine.
We upgraded to PHP 7.0 and the Xapian is not working.
Any help?
We are getting the following error.
PHP Fatal error:  UNHANDLED EXCEPTION! Error: Call to undefined function new_Database() in /usr/share/php/xapian.php:2100

Maybe Xapian needs an upgrade too.

Supported versions of PHP PHP7 was End of Live in January 2019 !

End of Life versions of PHP With migration advice

As you are upgrading PHP you should consider going all the way

we were using Xapian 1.2.24, upgraded to 1.2.25. but no luck

Post the code around line 2100.

function __construct($path_or_other=null) {
if (is_resource($path_or_other) && get_resource_type($path_or_other) === '_p_Xapian__Database') {
$this->_cPtr=$path_or_other;
return;
}
switch (func_num_args()) {
case 0: $this->_cPtr=new_Database(); break;
default: $this->_cPtr=new_Database($path_or_other);
}
}
